# Which best practice in Entity Framework queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
IQuerable x=db.Customers;
int sum1=x.where(c=>someCondtion).Sum(s=>s.Amount);
int sum2=x.where(c=>someCondtion).Sum(s=>s.Amount);
```

my question here is that the sum operation will be executed on the server side or the client side ?

OR

```
int sum1=db.Customers.where(c=>someCondtion).Sum(s=>s.Amount);
int sum2=db.Customers(c=>someCondtion).Sum(s=>s.Amount);
```

please any answer ?

Comment: Does last one even compile?

Comment: why are you using sum when you've filtered on a unique ID?

Comment: @teovankot none of them compile, C# is case-sensitive, so `where` won't work. last one won't work either though.

Comment: @Kai Question updated

Comment: Assigning `DbContext.Set<T>` result to variable doesn't fetch data from data source. They are equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what difference you think there is between

```
var table = db.SomeTable;
var result = table.Where(Predicate);
```

and

```
var result = db.SomeTable.Where(Predicate);
```

These 2 are 100 % equivalent.

One thing to consider is that no query is executed until it has to be because someone asked to see a concrete result. `Where` does nothing. `Sum` does, however. This means EF will generate some SQL and execute it. It will run on the DB (technically this depends on the `IQueryable` provider).

Basically, if the result of a query is another `IQueryable`, LINQ2Entities will probably be lazy about it. If the result is some primitive, or if you actually read some property of an entity loaded this way, then the query will execute.